# No service for type has been registered after publishing the website

Tags: asp.net-core, service, hosting

After publishing my website and running it through the console app, I get the error message No service for type 'SmartAdmin.WebUI.AppTenant' has been registered. It works perfectly well in VS2017

I use dependency injection on my login page which is loaded with an @inject
it uses SaasKit.Multitenancy, I did make sure that the dll is there as well

i expect the website to load without any issues after that has been resolved.

Comment: What is `SmartAdmin.WebUI.AppTenant`? How did you register and use it? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @TaoZhou it is Saaskit https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit it is regsitered in the following way `services.AddMultitenancy<AppTenant, AppTenantResolver>();` this works perfectly on localhost but on live it creates that problem